# When I set the image quality to 100 in ImagePicker, the image is pixelated after recovery

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem with Flutter's [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package, when I want to import an image from my gallery.  The problem is that even when I set the image quality to 100, the image is hugely pixelated after recovery.

I even try to withdraw the parameter `imageQuality` so that it takes the quality by Default, but the image is always pixelated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The ImagePicker package might compress the image when picked causing pixelation. Instead of the getImage method, use getLostData method to get a raw version of the image as Uint8List.

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
Uint8List? imageData;

void getImage() async {
  final PickedFile? pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    final LostDataResponse response = await _picker.getLostData();
    if (response.type == RetrieveType.image) {
      imageData = response.file!.bytes;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}
```

imageData contains the raw data of the image. You can display it using an Image.memory widget:

```
Image.memory(imageData)
```

Remember to call getImage inside a setState to update the UI after the image is picked.